# Synonym replacement for xml Elements with xslt in php senseful?

Tags: php, xslt, simplexml

i am indexing metadata in xml format (SimpleXML) with PHP. In process (and some later times) i want to rewrite (and delete) elements by their attributes/position/name . I guess that xslt is good for doing so but i am a bit scary because of performance. So it might be better to form a regexp as rule and edit directly with php? For these alternative i dislike that i could not find a manipulation syntax with help me further.

So how you do or would do this? 
Thanks for your help,
Robert

Comment: Regex is not good at manipulating XML. Using XSLT, why performance should be scary?

Comment: because if have to convert into DOM Object, because it is called often (more than once) and becuase of a bug in the simplexml/DOM exchange.. so if i iterate in simpleXML and convert a part of the node into DOM and convert back (with the import functions) the iteration is cancelled because object is somehow not the same.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, simple, short and easy -- universal XSLT solution. Whenever a transformation of an XML document is needed it would be a gross mistake not to use XSLT in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I doubt it is possible in the general case to express with a regular expression a delete/add/replace operation for a node at an arbitrary depth in an XML document (not to mention simultaneously satisfying other conditions such as based on attributes, namespace, depth, text-nodes).**

This explains why you couldn't find any such RegEx.

**On the other side any such operation is trivial with XSLT** and one writes the solution in half a minute and forgets about this "problem" because there are really more important things to do.

**For the record, below is an element renaming operation** (amy element named `a` is renamed to `h`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a">
  <h>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </h>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied for example to this XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d/>
            <a>
                <b>
                    <e>
                        <f>
                            <c>
                                <d>
                                    <a/>
                                </d>
                            </c>
                        </f>
                    </e>
                </b>
            </a>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<h>
   <b>
      <c>
         <d/>
         <h>
            <b>
               <e>
                  <f>
                     <c>
                        <d>
                           <h/>
                        </d>
                     </c>
                  </f>
               </e>
            </b>
         </h>
      </c>
   </b>
</h>
```

Comment: well thanks for your example. I used xslt in past with simpleXML already. As i mentioned in comment above it is not stable to exchange nodes in DOM with xslt when iterating in higher hierarchy.. you might be right that xslt is quite working..

Comment: @rokdd: XSLT was designed to be the language for XML transformations. It offers easiness and elegance and at the same time is very powerful. Definitely a tool that has its place in one's toolset.